# can an application change its own name in javaws?

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

Is there a way for a javaws application to change how it appears to the OS so that in a Windows taskbar, the user can see each instance of the application with a name that varies depending on what dataset is loaded?

For instance, at the command line, if they were to run (using three different dos windows)

```
javaws ThisApp.jnlp dataset1 
javaws ThisApp.jnlp dataset2
javaws ThisApp.jnlp dataset3
```

in the taskbar, they now see three instances of ThisApp.   Is there a way for the app itself to change the first instance of ThisApp to dataset1, the second instance of dataset2, etc?   (In reality the app is GUI based and the dataset is loaded using an interactive file browser, the command line example is just for clarification).

Hoping to do something similar to how when you hover over powerpoint in the taskbar, you get the name of each presentation that is open.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A) No.

B) JavaWS / jnlp is dead (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-deprecated-features-3745636.html).

Time to move on.

Comment: Is there a proposal for a replacement of any kind?

Comment: SInce both Java and Flash are pretty much dead in the browser, javascript is, as far as I know, the only thing left. I guess I'd go with an SPA - Angular , React, Vue? There's also asm.js, and WebAssembly is seeing some adoption, but not enough yet for general use.